# Windows 8 FormDataCollection not found in System.Net.Http.Formatting class

Tags: asp.net, http, windows-8, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a Windows 8 Application and I would like to use System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection to send the data to the server.

I've installed Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries 4.1.0-alpha-120809 from Nuget.

However, when I try to use FormDataCollection from System.Net.Http.Formatting class, it doesn't recognize it.

What am i missing?

Comment: Do you have add the dependencies library also ? Do you use the correct version ?

Comment: Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries 4.1.0-alpha-120809 is prelease version for .NETCore 4.5 i.e .NET for WinRT, so it's in still implementation phase, so it might have different class. Microsoft ASP.NET Web API Client Libraries 4.0.20710.0 is for .NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't really be using FormDataCollection for sending form content as it does not derive from HttpContent.  Do this instead.

```
  var form = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  form.Add("foo","bar");
  form.Add("boo","baz");
  var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("http://example.org/"), new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.Net.Http` and `System.Net.Http.Formatting` are two different assemblies. Make sure that you are addding `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly as a reference as well. It worked for me.